# AWS CloudWatch: Repeat Alert Notification after 24h of Alertstate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

i created some AWS CW Alerts which have typically a time periode of 1 hour / 1 Datapoint. By occuring an Alert our Service Team has been notificated. During a "normal" workday, someone cares about it and do the work of resetting some programms etc. But it also happens, no one have time or sense to care and the alert keeps in the alert state.

Now i want to repeat the alert if there wasn't any state-change in the past 24 hours. It is possible? I still does not find the "easy" answer.

Thx!

EDIT:
Added a "*daily_occurence_alert*" which is controlled by eventrules / time control. An additional alert for each observed Alert combined with an **AND** serves good.

It is a workaround, not a solution. Hope this feature will be added as a standard in future.